# String diversity

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

String diversity is the number of symbols that occur in the string at least once. Diversity of s will be denoted by d(s). For example , d("aaa")=1, d("abacaba")=3.

Given a string s, consisting of lowercase Latin letters. Consider all its substrings. Obviously, any substring diversity is a number from 1 to d(s). Find statistics about substrings diversity: for each k from 1 to d(s), find how many substrings of s has a diversity of exactly k.

EXAMPLE : let input string is "abca"

Then d(s)=3

We denote by s(i, j) a substring of "abca" with the indices in the segment [i, j].

```
s(1, 1) =  "a", d("a") = 1
s(2, 2) =  "b", d("b") = 1
s(3, 3) =  "c", d("c") = 1
s(4, 4) =  "a", d("a") = 1
s(1, 2) =  "ab", d("ab") = 2
s(2, 3) =  "bc", d("bc") = 2
s(3, 4) =  "ca", d("ca") = 2
s(1, 3) =  "abc", d("abc") = 3
s(2, 4) =  "bca", d("bca") = 3
s(1, 4) =  "abca", d("abca") = 3
```

Total number of substring with diversity 1 is 4, with diversity 2 equals 3, 3 diversity is 3.

How to find it if the length of s is from 1 to 3·10^5.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  My first thought is that you could reduce the problem to strings that have no repeated adjacent letters by absorbing all the runs that use only one letter to a single letter.  For example you could reduce $bacaaaaab$ to a word $baca^5b$ and think about how to correctly count substrings that contain the symbol $a^5$.  You could try similar tricks for repeated pairs of letters, etc.